# Changing parent directory (../) with symlinks

Tags: bash, cd-command

I have a symlink

```
~/link -> ~/a/really/long/path
```

When I do

```
cd ~/link
cd ..
```

it takes me to

```
~
```

but I want to go to

```
~/a/really/long
```

Is there a way to do this?

I am using bash.

Comment: You mean `cd ~/a/really/long/path` then `cd ..` puts you in `~` at the moment?  I can't reproduce that.

Comment: @Mikel: No, first create a symlink to `~/a/really/long/path` then cd to that then to `..`. You should end up back in ~ (assuming that's where you started).

Comment: Is my edit accurate?  I couldn't understand the question before.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Bash (as well as ksh, zsh, and even ash) track directory changes so that `cd /foo/bar && cd ..` always takes you to `/foo` even if `bar` is a symlink. Pass the `-P` option to `cd` to ignore the tracked change and follow the “physical” directory structure:

```
cd -P ..
```

See `help cd` or `man builtins` for documentation about the bash builtin `cd`.
If you really dislike the directory tracking feature, you can turn it off with `set -P` in bash (`set -o no_chase_link` in zsh).

Comment: The way I read the question, the OP has `-P` or `-o physical` already set?

Comment: +1, but suggest link to man page.

Comment: @Mikel: No, the question says that he is following the symbolic link, not the physical directory structure.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't actually try to edit your post. Suggested edit submitted now.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use readlink to find the physical path to this directory, then go one directory higher:

```
cd $(readlink -f .)/..
```

Answer (score 3):

One method you could use is to use an alias instead of a symlink to take you to ~/a/really/long/path. That's the method I use, since then I can just type a simple 1/2/et cetera letter command instead of cd symlink