# Understanding directory symlinks traversals and the parent directory

Tags: shell, directory, symlink, cd-command

Let's say you have directories `/dir1` and `/dir2/linked`, where the latter is a symlink to the former.

When you `cd` to `linked` and `pwd`, you get the output `/dir2/linked`. If you then `cd ..`, you'll be put on `/dir2`. This behaviour is consistent with the concept of you being in `/dir2/linked` before. However, as I understand it, the parent directory (`..`) of any directory is stored in the directory inode (i.e.:physically in the disk). Obviously,  since `/dir2/linked` is really `/dir1`, the parent directory on the inode must be `/`

To further complicate matters, while inside `/dir2/linked`, the outputs of `ls ..` and `cd .. ; ls .` are different! It seems like `cd` honors the symlinked path, while `ls` honors the "physical" path. As mentioned in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11044/changing-parent-directory-with-symlinks), there's `cd -P` for this use case, though.

`man pwd` mentions "physical" and "logical" working directories, but I still have a few questions at this point:

- Is this behaviour always provided by the `PWD` environment variable, as mentioned in `man pwd`?
- Why do default `cd` and `ls` have different behaviours, if they're both shell commands (i.e.: not programs)?
- Does the typical *program* (not shell command) use `PWD` instead of the physical path? I realize it's up to the implementation, but is there any rule of thumb?

Comment: A lot of info in [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79621)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That's a fantastic answer, thanks for sharing

Comment: You're welcome. Please feel free to copy-paste text from there if you plan to make your own answer to your own question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bash` "knows" about symlinks and tracks this info when you use a symlink to enter a directory.

You can check this by doing the following in your example:

```
$ cd /dir2
$ cd linked
$ pwd
/dir2/linked
$ PWD='' bash -c pwd
/dir1
```

You need to start the bash with an empty `PWD` variable, otherwise it uses that trick to display the "fake" path.

Note that `ls` *is* a separate program and as such doesn't have bash's knowledge of how you arrived at the current directory, so `ls ..` will just show the contents of the *real* parent directory, not relative to the symlink you followed.

Most programs will not depend on the environment variable `CWD` as there are many ways of starting programs, via the bash shell is just one so it's not reliable to expect `CWD` to contain the correct value (try setting `CWD` to something wrong before doing `bash -c pwd`, you can see it checks the value for sanity).

Comment: it's useful to know that you clear `PWD` like so, but by itself this doesn't answer the questions I mentioned

Comment: Added some more info.

Comment: I was under the impression `ls` was provided by bash, but you and `help` convinced me otherwise. That makes things a lot clearer, thanks!

Comment: `PWD` is standard in POSIX.  You can rely on it to be set.  If it is not set, things could break, for example the `pwd` [utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pwd.html): See also [Environment variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html).