# Inside a linked folder, doing "ls" to relative paths outside it shows the contents pointed by linked directory, not the source. Is this correct?

Tags: symlink

Suppose this directory structure:

```
/folder1/
/folder2/
```

Now, if I enter

```
cd /folder1
ln -s /folder2 linkToFolder2
cd /folder1/linkToFolder2
ls ..
```

I thought that, given that pwd is /folder1/linkToFolder2, doing a "ls .." would return /folder1's contents. However, it is returning folder2's. Is this behavior correct?

Comment: Does it answer your question? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180620/understanding-directory-symlinks-traversals-and-the-parent-directory

Answer (score 0):

Your link points to /folder2.Your pwd is /folder1/linkToFolder2, that is the same than /folder2/, and 'ls ..' in all the cases should show you the above directory, whether if you are in /folder1 or /folder2