# Relative symlinks not resolving in subdirectory

Tags: bash, symlink

I've got the following directory layout:

```
/home/me/mydir
  \- tiller -> ./cache/git-repo1/subdir1/tiller
  \- makefiles -> ./cache/git-repo2/subdir2/makefiles
```

When I'm in `/home/me/mydir` if I type `ls -l` I get the above as expected.

However, if I change into `/home/me/mydir/tiller` and type `ls ../makefiles` I get an error: `ls: ../makefiles: No such file or directory`

How can I access `/home/me/mydir/makefiles` using a relative path from `/home/me/mydir/tiller`, or is my only option to use an absolute path?

**Edit**: I guess I'm hitting [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180620/understanding-directory-symlinks-traversals-and-the-parent-directory). Is there a solution? I really need `<cmd> ../makefiles` to work from within `/home/me/mydir/tiller`.

Comment: @A.B I've updated the tree to more accurately reflect the layout of .cache

Answer (score 1):

Since I actually want to make includes in Makefiles work, I've changed my `include` to take a value from an environment variable, which I set to the absolute path of `/home/me/mydir`, i.e.:

```
CACHE_ROOT?=..
include $(CACHE_ROOT)/makefiles/base.mk
```

After reading [this great answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79571/symbolic-link-recursion-what-makes-it-reset/79621#79621), I realised absolute paths were the only solution.