# ls .. doesn't work properly with symlinks

Tags: bash, command-line, zsh, symlink

I have directories set up a bit like this

```
~/code
~/code/src
~/code/build -> /path/to/somewhere/else
```

That last one's a symlink.

If I do this

```
cd ~/code/build
ls ..
```

then I get the listing for `/path/to/somewhere`, but from [other remarks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11044/changing-parent-directory-with-symlinks) and my own experience, I'd expected to see the listing for `~/code` -- I'd swear that this used to work the other way round.

I'm using zsh and bash on Ubuntu. Is there a setting for this or is it deeply ingrained into POSIX or something?

Comment: `ls -- "$(dirname -- "$PWD")"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not the issue of `ls`. It's how symlinks work. The `..` gets you into the parent of the current directory, the directory doesn't know you got to it through a symlink. The shell has to intervene to prevent this behaviour. For the shell builtin `cd`, there is special handling that doesn't just call `chdir` but memorizes the full directory path and tries to figure out what you want. `ls`, however, is not a builtin. The shell has to change `..` to a different path before passing it to `ls` if you want to get what you expect. `zsh` option `CHASE_DOTS` helps you with that.

Generally speaking, symlinks to directories are a dirty business. For critical and semi-permanent applications, rather use `mount --bind`.

Comment: I don't get it. I've tried `setopt CHASE_DOTS` and `unsetopt CHASE_DOTS` in ~/.zshrc (with restart) also tried `unsetopt` and combinations. Nothing seemed to make a difference. Also, doesn't the shell interpret ".." before passing it to both `cd` and `ls`?

Comment: Sorry, I checked it now and it appears that all these options only work for `cd`. `zsh` is not substituting the filenames given to other commands (kind of obvious now, it can't actually know what is a filename and what isn't). I don't think this will ever work as you wanted. The closest thing I can imagine to actually get the parent directory you came from is to replace `..` with `$(cd .. && pwd)`. This launches a subshell that `cd`'s there and reads the link. But generally speaking, don't use symlinks to directories. Use bind mounting.

Comment: `mount --bind` works, but I anticipate a problem if I add the line to fstab, my home directory is encrypted so an entry which looks like `/path/to/somewhere/else /home/me/code/build none rw,bind, 0 0` will fail won't it?

Comment: It depends on the order, it should work, if the home is already mounted.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged your question with `zsh` I assume we are talking about this shell.

Most probably you have set (either directly or indirectly with some external script like `oh-my-zsh`) the variables `CHASE_LINKS` and/or `CHASE_DOTS`. To confirm that run `setopt | grep -i chase` and see if they are listed. If they are, just unset them:

```
unsetopt CHASE_DOTS
unsetopt CHASE_LINKS
```